# Sort two list of jobs result in minimum execution time

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving, sorting

Two twins, James Johnson and Jonathan Johnson, work at a factory which produces bicycles. Their job is probably the most important one: James attaches the front wheel, and Jonathan does the same with the rear wheel. At the beginning of their working day, they receive  construction kits, consisting of the front wheel, the rear wheel, and the rest of the bicycle. It is known that:

- for the i-th construction kit, James will attach the front wheel in Ai seconds;
- for the i-th construction kit, Jonathan will attach the rear wheel Bi in  seconds;
- James and Jonathan cannot work on the same bicycle simultaneously;
- the front wheel must be attached earlier than the rear wheel.

James and Jonathan are very experienced in assembling bicycles. In fact, given the information about all construction kits, they act optimally, such that the last wheel is attached as early as possible. However, the new director of the factory is not yet that experienced, so she needs some help. Please write her a program which tells how fast the twins assemble all today's bicycles, and how exactly this could be done.

**Input**

The first line of the input file contains N, the number of bicycle construction kits.

The second line contains N integers, the i-th of them equals Ai. The third line also contains N integers, the i-th of them equals Bi. All Ai and Bi are positive and do not exceed 10^9.

**Output**

In the first line, output the minimum time needed to assemble all bicycles.

The second line must contain  integers. Of them, the i-th integer denotes the moment of time James starts to assemble the i-th construction kit.
The third line must contain  integers, this time for Jonathan.
If several optimal scenarios exist, output any of them.

Examples

input.txt
3

1 2 3

2 1 3

output.txt
8

0 4 1

1 7 4

My solution is a greedy approach, sorting the sequences of pair (Ai, Bi) and (Ai+1, Bi+1). If execute the sequence in order i+1 -> i takes less time that i -> i+1, then swap them.
So far it passes 13 test cases and fails on a test case with quite close result. The expected output is 29 while my solution yields 31. If anybody can help please give me a hint, thank you in advance.

I use Java, I implement a class called Job which stores a pair of Ai, Bi and the original index.

```
static class Job implements Comparable<Job> {
    long a;
    long b;
    int index;

    public Job(long a, long b, int index) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Job that) {
        long thisTime = this.a + Math.max(this.b, that.a) + that.b;
        long thatTime = that.a + Math.max(this.a, that.b) + this.b;

        return Long.compare(thisTime, thatTime);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + a + "," + b + ") - " + index;
    }
}

public static void solve(long[] a, long[] b, int[] order) throws IOException {
    long[][] start = new long[2][a.length];
    int prev = -1;
    for (int i : order) {
        if (prev == -1) {
            start[0][i] = 0;
            start[1][i] = a[i];
        } else {
            start[0][i] = start[0][prev] + a[prev];
            start[1][i] = Math.max(start[1][prev] + b[prev], start[0][i] + a[i]);
        }

        prev = i;
    }

    long time = start[1][prev] + b[prev];
    bw.write(time + "\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < start.length; ++i) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < start[0].length; ++j)
            sb.append(start[i][j] + " ");
        bw.write(sb.toString().trim() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the input that should produce the answer $29.$  Also, you had better show us your algorithm in more detail.

Comment: It seems ambiguous whether all the parts for a bicycle must come from the same indexed construction kit or not.

Comment: @saulspatz it's just the hint from the judge, they don't show the actual input.

Comment: Sounds like an application test for a dev-job...

Comment: @denklo no, I'm following an algorithm course of ITMO on edx.org

Comment: I don't understand what you code is doing.  The whole point of the problem is to minimize the time that Jonathon spends waiting for James to attach a wheel.  Where is that reflected?  The greedy approach would seem to be for James to work on the bicycles in the order of increasing time to attach the front wheel (shortest time first in other words) breaking ties in the order of the longest time to attach the rear wheel.  We want to get Jonathon started working as soon as possible, and we want to keep him busy as long as possible.  I'm not saying this is the answer, just that it's greedy.

Comment: This website has a policy for not helping with ongoing contest problems, so you should show a link to the original question to show that it isn't a contest problem.

Comment: @saulspatz as mentioned above, for two adjacent bicycles Ai Bi and Ai+1 Bi+1 if we execute with the order of Ai+1, Bi+1 yields less time than Ai Bi first then swap Ai+1, Bi+1

Comment: @DanielV this is not a contest, the course is $99 so it is obvious that the content is private to the student. However if you still want proof I can show you a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, but where are you computing the time?

Comment: anyway, this is the kind of problem that is probably better suited to cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielV thanks for your suggestion, I will post on that site for other stuff like this

Comment: @saulspatz 
        long thisTime = this.a + Math.max(this.b, that.a) + that.b;
        long thatTime = that.a + Math.max(this.a, that.b) + this.b;

Comment: Yes, I can see the line of code, but I don't understand how that is computing anything relevant to the problem.  Anyway, the solution is given by [Johnson's algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling#Problem_variations)

Comment: @saulspatz I've read that algorithm before, but in this case we have two list of jobs even the "machines" have to run in async with each other.

Comment: You have a list of jobs with two processes, one of which must proceed the other.  It  is exactly the two-machine job shop scheduling problem.

Comment: @saulspatz oh sorry I didn't realize it at first, now I see the identical, thank you.

Comment: @saulspatz It's weird, when I apply the algorithm for the example above, for (3,3) if we put it in L1, we have L1 = {3, 1}, L2 = {2}, total processing time is 9. Likewise, when we choose (3,3) to put into L2, we have L1 = {1}, L2 = {2,3}, total processing time is also 9, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @saulspatz someone has messed with the content of that page on Wiki, it should be end of L1 and beginning of L2.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  [This wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_rule) has the rule correct.  I'm going to make an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job shop scheduling problem.  We can view James and Jonathon as two machines, each of which performs a specific process.  Each job requires two processes performed in the same order for every job.

Although job shop scheduling is NP-complete in general, the two-machine instance can be solved in polynomial time by [Johnson's rule.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_rule)

Comment: I've implemented the code as Johnson's algorithm but it got RE with a specific test cases. I've posted the code on code review. 
If can check my code here, I've written unit test with all kind of input but I couldn't regenerate the error.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219238/runtime-error-with-specific-input-johnsons-algorithm-for-scheduling

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough java to answer your question.  Sorry.

Comment: I've successfully fixed the problem, it is due to TimShort in Java Arrays.sort, quite a headache to figure it out, because I couldn't see the log, I need help from the judge system to get the error log. Anyway, thanks for reminding me about this algorithm. :D